# Как можно перезаписать текст который находится в textarea?

Tags: php, ajax

Как можно перезаписать текст в файле который находится в textarea из веб-страницы?

```
<textarea>какой-то текст</textarea>
```

Comment: Сформируйте внятно задачу. Переписать можно многими способами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeText() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "Another Text";
}
```

```html
<textarea>Text</textarea>

<button onclick="changeText()">Change text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Js

Если обращаться по ID то так:

```
document.getElementById('myTextareaId').value = "MyText";
```

Если по классу то:

```
document.getElementByClassName('myTextareaClass').value = "MyText";
```

Где MyTextareaClass/myTextareaId - индификатор текстового поля, а MyText - нужный текст

Comment: `getElementByClass` - такой функции нет, есть `getElementsByClassName`